# Forwarding a request from servlet to .jsp fails when deployed on remote server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, forward

I have been stuck with this problem for two days now and I cant find a solution.
I have this project structure as above:
[image]
I want to forward a request from `Survey`(it is a Servlet) to `survey.jsp`.
Now when I deploy this from `IntelliJ` on localhost the forward is made with success. Now i take the `.war` and use the `Tomcat Apache` manager to deploy it to a dedicated Server.
When i call `dedicatedserverip:8080` the `index.jsp` loads properly as in `localhost:8080`. But when it comes to forward there are two cases:

1. When the name of `.war` file is different from `survey.war` when the forward happens I get error 404 . (In this case I think that the request is forwarded  to `dedicatedserverip:8080`)
2. When the name of `.war` file is `survey.war` when forward happens it happens to load again `index.jsp` page. (in this case I think the request is forwarded  to `dedicatedserverip:8080/survey`)

Below is the code I use to forward the request:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/survey.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Now my question is: Is there something done wrong? Or is there something that I must understand that I haven't? How can I fix it and get the needed result as in localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. It had nothing to do with the forward, the problem was in the submit form action. Action was `action="/survey"`. I replaced with `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/survey` . And it solved the problem. This explains why the index page was called when `.war` name was `survey.war`and error page when it was different.
Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried forwarding relative instead of absolute?

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("survey.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Then additionally it should be no problem if you change the name of your war file and with it the ServletContext of the application any more.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I wasted a lot of time with such a small mistake of mine. You will find the solution to my own answer